# Unable to access certain sites in mac

Tags: safari, google-chrome

I have just moved from a Windows laptop to a macbook air and I am facing an issue that certain web-sites are not loading in my mac - both Safari and Chrome browsers. In chrome I am getting the error as ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and in Safari it shows as Server is not responding

Again reiterating, its only for a few sites I am getting this message and others are working fine. Any idea what I need to check?

P.S - On initial googling I have added both the browsers to the firewall exception list.
Also please note that I am completely new to a mac and so need explicit instructions to follow (sorry for that - but till now I havent used anything else except Windows!!)

Let me know if I need to provide any other info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post from the Apple Support Communities might help: [Link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7406435?start=0&tstart=0)

Things to try according to this post:

- Settings/Networks/Advanced/Proxys, Discover new proxys
- Check the ignored domains for blocked domains
- Safari/Preferences/Advanced - enable the Develop menu, then empty caches
- Safari/History/Show History - delete all history items
- Restart your router (obvious one, but often works well)

One other thing to try:
 - Change the DNS server to Google: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Comment: Thanks for the options. The other steps didnt resolve anything but changing DNS to Google helped!